# React: Passing function from external parent component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am currently trying to understand how to access a function in a child component in TypeScript, which is defined in a parent component.

The structure of the components is as followed:

1. Parent Component (including a getDatafromForm function)
2. Two child components that are siblings (Child1, Child2)
3. One of the children (Child1) calls a component, so to say the Child of Child1. This is a form and looks like this:
4. What I want to achieve is to call get the data from the form, which is generated in 3. by calling the parent component (getDataFromForm) from  Child1.

   ```
    import React from "react";
    import { useForm, SubmitHandler } from "react-hook-form";

    type FormInputs = {
        min: number;
        max: number;
      };
    // const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FormInputs> = data => 
    console.log(data);

    export default function ChildofChild1(props: { getDataFromForm: (arg0: any) => void; }) {
      const { register, formState: { errors }, handleSubmit, getValues } = useForm<FormInputs>({
        defaultValues: {
        min: 250,
        max: 8000,
      }
       });
      const onSubmit = (dataFreq: any) => {

        props.getDataFromForm(dataFreq) //Call the function in the parent component
      }


      return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <input {...register("min", { required: true })} />
          {errors.min && "Only numbers are allowed"}
          <input {...register("max", { required: true })} />
          {errors.max && "Only numbers are allowed"}
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
      );
    }
   ```

I am calling this component from Child1, which is described below:

```
import React from "react";
import ChildofChild1 from "./ChildChild1"

type Props = {

}
type State = {

}
export default class Child1 extends React.Component<Props, State>{
// getDataFromForm = (data: any) => {
//   this.setState({data: data })
// };
render() {

  return (
       <ChildofChild1 getDataFromForm={this.props.getDataFromForm}/>
  );
}
}
```

The thing that is working is to call the getDataFromForm within the component, as seen in the commented block. The issue here is that I would want to have the received that from ChildofChild1 available in a sibiling component Child2. That is why I am creating a parent component with the commented block. This parent component function looks like this:

```
export function getDataFromForm(data: any) {
    
    this.setState({data: data });
    
    return data;
  }
```

In the sibling of Child1 component, which would be Child2, I would like to call this function with

```
var data = getDataFromForm(data);
```

What do I miss? I thought of binding the parent function but the function doesn't get called.

Comment: add `props` to the function like `props.GetDataFromForm(data)`. That's how it works in Javascript, not sure if its the same in Type Script. I think @rehman_00001 got it right

Comment: Passing a callback from parent to child and calling is trivial, i.e. `props.getDataFromForm(....)`, but I'm getting hung up on your "In a sibling of Child component, I would like to call this function with..." comment. All children will have the same callback. What are you really trying to accomplish, i.e. what problem are you trying to solve for by passing this callback?

Comment: Seems to be classic example of [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) where the state and callback is in the parent component and you pass them down as props to children (and they can pass to their children, etc.....). Are all these grandchildren components needing their own specific state in the parent, or is it a shared state and any child/grandchild can stomp on the state value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly. Probably the examples with better component names would help. Let me know if my understanding is correct!

1. You have a `Parent` component and a `Child` component.
2. `Parent` component has a function: `getDataFromForm` defined inside
3. You are trying to access that function inside `Child` component. If this is correct, checkout the below code (Else, please revise your question).

```js
// Parent.tsx

type Props = {}
type State = {}

class Parent extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  public getDataFromForm = () => {
    this.setState({ data: data });
  }
  
  public render(): JSX.Element {
    return <Child getDataFromForm={this.getDataFromForm} />;
  }
}


// Child.tsx

type Props = {
  // This method will be available in props for the child component
  getDataFromForm: () => void
}

class Child extends React.Component<Props, State> {  
  public render(): JSX.Element {
    this.props.getDataFromForm(); // <== You can call the parent's method through props
    return <>... </>; // Your JSX here
  }
}
```

Comment: @rehman_00001, I just edited my question. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @JustDebuggin Yes, but it was poorly explained from my side

Comment: Kindly mark it as accepted if my answer helps @chrischris96

Comment: It kind of did not help but it was the correct answer. I gave you the correct answer points

Comment: God bless you :) @chrischris96